# Can i make a flutter dropdown button that only drops to the bottom (It should float only down, even if i select the last option)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I used the same example from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

but when i choose the option from below the list, then when i reopen the list it floats upwards

Can i do such that, it only drops down

Comment: You mean even when there are no rooms to display bottom?

Comment: @Balasanka, No, there is more than enough room for the drop-down